# Manage Borders in nested tables

Tags: html, css

#### This is my html table code and i need to apply border for inner table only not for outer table

```
<table border = "0">
<tr>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>
<table border = "1">
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
</table>
</td>
</<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You already have that.

Comment: yes i guess you want border for second table td only right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you

**html**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>somedata</td>
<td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
      <td>somedata</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</<tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table table tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use css border property with a selector that targets a `<table>` that is a descendant of a `<td>`

```css
td table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Or** add a class to whatever you want to have a border, the `<table>`, the containing `<td>`, or both:

```css
.bordered {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td>somedata</td>
    <td class="bordered">
      <table class="bordered">
        <tr>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
          <td>somedata</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```